# get the values of the many columns in a sheet with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a DataBase that update depending a values of other sheet, and I need to save the values in a list. Basically I want to do the same of the code behind but with a many columns, for example with the range G8:G; H8:H, etc.

```
var hojaActual = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
function item() {

 var data = hojaActual.getRange('F8:F').getValues();
 //var items = [];
 //Para los ítems ver https://juansguzman.com/blog/2021/10/15/entendiendo-el-getrange-en-google-apps-script-y-google-sheets/ quizás se pueda hacer un ciclo creando una lista aquí 
 var elementos = [];


 data.forEach( row => {
   if (elementos.indexOf(row[0])  == -1){
    elementos.push(row[0]); 
    
   }
 })  
 
//Logger.log('ITEMS: '+items)
Logger.log('ELEMENTOS: '+elementos)


//Desde aquí es nuevo
const carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById('1Quh05F93TR_NL3S9tS-U3jVdhwk')

const idForm = "1Gn7cXU9l5MtoAelMt4gLmdj6mK1A2kAhswo";
const formulario = FormApp.openById(idForm);
const preguntas = formulario.getItems();
 formulario1234= formulario.addCheckboxItem().setTitle("Funciono a medias")
                                   .setChoiceValues(elementos)
    
}
```

I think the best way is have a variable with the number of column but i dont know how to do with a ForEach

I think the best it's have a variable with the number of column but i dont know how to do with a ForEach

Answer (score 1):

**"Many Columns"**

- Create an array and populate it with the ranges that you want to process. For example:

  - `var rangeList = ['F8:F','G8:G','H8:H']`
- Loop through the array of Ranges.

  - `for (var i=0;i<rangeList.length;i++){`
  - `var data = hojaActual.getRange(rangeList[i]).getValues()`